# What layout should I use to have scrolling for two elements

Tags: android, android-layout

Here is my layout situations.

```
<LinearLayout>

     <CustomGallery android:id="myComplextGallery"></CustomGallery>

     <LinearLayout android:id="galleryFooterToSelectGalleryItem> 
        .... Footer elements  Pick an item in gallery
     </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The behavior that I am after is the same as if myComplexGallery where a list item in a list view containing just one list item, and the footer was a ListView footer.  That is it scrolls with the content. Note the gallery is a full-screen gallery.

So I could put the CustomGallery in a ListView, but is this overkill?  Is there another way to to do this.  Using a scrollview only allows one direct sub-view+ the Custom Galery must also scroll down.  It has an Image and lots and lots of words.

I want the footer linear layout to scroll with the CustomGallery so I was wondering what options are there beside ListView and is ListView perhaps the right approach after all. My concern with making CustomGallery a listItem is that it is quite complex in its own right, having its own adapter, and list of items.  To make a list view that will always contain just one item, albeit a complex one does quite seem right ... but just wondering what are the alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

ViewPager with a xml layout you designed inflated inside of it. Then pragmatically set the data in the `onPageScrolled(int position, float offset, int offsetPixels)` method.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html